# The require rights for listEventSourceMappings on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I execute follow function on AWS Lambda.

```
params = {
  Marker: "", 
  MaxItems: 123
};
lambda.listEventSourceMappings(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else console.log(data); // successful response
});
```

This permission error occurred.

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::12334567778:assumed-
role/xxxxxx/yyyyyy is not authorized to perform: 
lambda:ListEventSourceMappings
at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-
sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
```

I try same rights on IAM.
But same error occurred.
Do you know the rights for ListEventSourceMappings?

Answer (score 1):

The required permission is actually called `lambda:ListEventSourceMappings`.

See [Actions and Condition Context Keys for AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_lambda.html) in the IAM User Guide for the complete list.